# How do I open the web browser window from a VS extension?

Tags: visual-studio-sdk

When the user opens a solution in Visual Studio, I'd like to open the web browser window, pointing at a particular page.

In my extension, I've successfully hooked the `OnAfterOpenSolution` event, and now I'd like to open the web browser window.

How do I do that?

(Note that I'm not referring to the user's default browser; I mean the browser window integrated in VS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
dte.ItemOperations.Navigate("http://www.google.fr",
     vsNavigateOptions.vsNavigateOptionsDefault);
```

Comment: I actually figured it out back in June; should have answered my own question ;-)